# java using pdfbox to add pictures with signature

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, digital-signature

I tried the example：CreateVisualSignature2.java,but it didn't work. Why can't my picture be displayed, but can click on the area where the picture is displayed, and the picture information can also be displayed after clicking, but the picture cannot be seen.

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage(srcDoc.getPage(pageNum).getMediaBox());
doc.addPage(page);

PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc);
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);
PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
signatureField.setValue(signature);

List<PDField> acroFormFields = acroForm.getFields();
acroForm.setSignaturesExist(true);
acroForm.setAppendOnly(true);
acroForm.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
acroFormFields.add(signatureField);

widget.setRectangle(rect);
widget.setPage(page);
page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(doc);
PDResources res = new PDResources();
PDRectangle bbox = new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
form.setResources(res);
form.setFormType(1);
form.setBBox(bbox);

COSArray procSet = new COSArray();
procSet.add(COSName.getPDFName("PDF"));
procSet.add(COSName.getPDFName("Text"));
procSet.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageB"));
procSet.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageC"));
procSet.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageI"));
res.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET,procSet);

PDFormXObject frm = new PDFormXObject(doc);
PDResources res1 = new PDResources();
res.put(COSName.getPDFName("FRM"),frm);

frm.setResources(res1);
frm.setFormType(1);
frm.setBBox(bbox);

PDExtendedGraphicsState extGState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
extGState.setAlphaSourceFlag(false);
extGState.setBlendMode(BlendMode.DARKEN);
extGState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(1.0f);
extGState.setStrokingOverprintControl(true);
res1.put(COSName.getPDFName("Ext"),extGState);
res1.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET,procSet);

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image,"png", bao);
bao.flush();
byte[] imageByte = bao.toByteArray();
bao.close();

PDImageXObject ximage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, imageByte, null);
COSDictionary images = new COSDictionary();
images.setItem("Sign0",ximage);
res1.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.XOBJECT,images);

PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
widget.setAppearance(appearance);

PDAppearanceStream pdAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(frm.getCOSObject());
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, pdAppearanceStream);

contentStream.drawImage(ximage,0, 0,rect.getWidth(),rect.getHeight());

contentStream.close();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

doc.save(baos);
doc.close();
return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the result PDF and mention what PDFBox version you're using.

Comment: version ：pdfbox:2.0.20

Comment: The current version is 2.0.23. And you shared an image, but I need the PDF. I also see you made changes in the code, the original code doesn't have `BlendMode.DARKEN`.

Comment: I don't know how to upload pdf to you，I refer to CreateVisualSignature2.java （https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature2.java#L447）

Comment: Yeah but that example doesn't have `BlendMode.DARKEN` so this shows you modified the example. The best is usually to start with the example, see that it works, and then modify step by step. To upload the PDF use a sharehoster like dropbox, google drive or filedropper.com .

Comment: Thanks. I see the upper form XObject `form` is empty. You never create a content stream for that one, only for the lower XObject, `frm`. (I used PDFDebugger to see that)

Comment: You need to do something like `fcs.drawForm(frm)` where fcs is a `PDFormContentStream`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used adobe acrobat pro to check the internal structure and found that the `form` contains `frm`. I mistakenly thought that the form contains the content stream.And I added `contentStream.drawForm(frm)`above the code of `contentStream.close()`,but it was invalid

Comment: both have content streams. The one in `Root/Pages/Kids/[0]/Annots/[0]/AP/N/Resources/XObject/FRM` is probably correct. The one in `Root/Pages/Kids/[0]/Annots/[0]/AP/N` is empty which explains that you see nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying to add a content stream to the missing

Comment: According to your help, I added a few lines of code, `PDAppearanceStream pdStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
        PDPageContentStream cStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, pdStream);
        cStream.drawForm(frm);
        cStream.close();`, the chapter can indeed be displayed, thank you very much.

Comment: I would like to ask a question. When the pdf file is opened in `Sublime Text3`, is there a way to display the object code of the image resource before the object code of the seal, for example,`Sign0 (22 0 obj)`  before `SubFilter (17 0 obj)`?,thanks.

Comment: I can't help there, I don't use "Sublime Text3".

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code：

```
PDAppearanceStream pdStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());         
PDPageContentStream cStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, pdStream);         
cStream.drawForm(frm);         
cStream.close();
```

Thank you very much Tilman Hausherr.